# Activity and Places navigation issue with Google Chrome

Tags: java, gwt

I have a strange issue with Activity and Places navigation and Google Chrome. When I try to navigate using buttons which call goTo(), I can see quickly my places loaded then I returned to default place. Everything work fine on Firefox AND on Google Chrome with DevMode. I would like to try with SuperDevMode but I can't see source map on Chrome (I asked on an other thread about that).

I can't find any known bug about Places navigation and Chrome. What can I do wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

Today I have time to investigate on this. I added logs on my PlaceController and saw that goTo function is called with default place when current place is started. I can't understand where the event is fired. Something weird, the place name don't appear on the URL bar (#MyPlace: )

Again, everything work fine on other browser and on Chrome with devMode and when it works, I always see place name on URL bar.

Comment: There is no bug - all my apps work fine in Chrome and in all other browsers. There must be something going on in your code.

Comment: Do you have your places listed in your PlaceHistoryMapper. I will sometimes forget to add them there and it causes odd issues where the tokenizer cannot be found for the place.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw yes all my places are listed on my PlaceHistoryMapper. Remember that everything work fine in DevMode. That's why I thought it could be a bug. Do you see anything else I can check ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you are going to have to show us some code. I agree this has to be something with your code that is causing this problem. Mainly the PlaceHistoryMapper, ActivityMapper and how you constructed them would really help. Do you have any instances of GWT.isClient() or GWT.isProdMode(). This could be why something works in dev mode and not prod mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ChrisHinshaw, we found the problem. We had an ugly "RootPanel.getBodyElement().removeAllChildren();" used to remove a "loading" div on our html page. This code was on a test "if(GWT.isProdMode())" that's why we don't have the bug with devMode. I don't understand yet why it causes only a bug with Chrome. Perhaps the behaviour of this command is different with IE and FF and don't remove iframe. I haven't time to try but if someone want to..

Thank everyone who tried to help.